# Oracle: Set NLS_PARAMETERS with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, regional

I found out my servers, running Oracle 10g, were not initializing with the same NLS_SORT value when using the sqlplus binary.

Is there a way to set the default NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS for every instance of sqlplus?

PS: The idea is **not** to do an ALTER SESSION at the beginning of every sql script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the NLS parameters are specified by the client application. `SQL*Plus` on windows will have its parameters defined in the registry (same as the `ORACLE_HOME` where it is installed). On *nix systems the paremeters are defined as environment variable.

You can find additionnal information in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#sthref186).

Answer (score 0):

Use an ON LOGON trigger to do the ALTER SESSION?

Then you can do it in one place and won't have have to change every client.